# Override RSA private key operation for Smart Card?

Tags: c++, cryptography, rsa, smartcard, crypto++

I am implementing smart card middleware and I need to add RSA-PSS signature scheme to it. I wish I could override the code in Crypto++ which is responsible for private key operation and get everything else for free (PSS and PKCS padding). I figured this code in `rsa.cpp` is what I want to rewrite differently for smart cards:

```
Integer InvertibleRSAFunction::CalculateInverse(RandomNumberGenerator &rng, const Integer &x) const
{
    DoQuickSanityCheck();
    ModularArithmetic modn(m_n);
    Integer r, rInv;
    do {    // do this in a loop for people using small numbers for testing
        r.Randomize(rng, Integer::One(), m_n - Integer::One());
        rInv = modn.MultiplicativeInverse(r);
    } while (rInv.IsZero());
...
```

First I thought this can be done by subclassing `RSA::PrivateKey`

```
class MyPrivKey : public RSA::PrivateKey {
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    MyPrivKey(Args&&... args) : RSA::PrivateKey(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    Integer CalculateInverse(RandomNumberGenerator &rng, const Integer &x) const override {
      return ... // do some smart card magic
    }
};
```

And then passing this key to the `signer` object

```
MyPrivateKey privateKey(params);

// Signer object
RSASS<PSS, SHA1>::Signer signer(privateKey);
```

But soon I found out that all components of `privateKey` (modulus, private and public exponent, etc.) are just copied to `signer` internals. So overriding `RSA::PrivateKey::CalculateInverse` doesn't really help.

Then I got lost in the templates and cried. I guess there's 0.0001% chance someone can help me with this. I'll try my luck.

Full code of my example https://pastebin.com/Nwk4jX0j

Comment: Does `Signer` actually *use* those values, or does it call `PrivateKey::CalculateInverse()`?  If the latter, you can give it some bogus values to copy, and do your private magic on the smartcard.  Does the smartcard not come with a suitable library anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I figured out I need to subclass more things

```
class SmartCardPrivateKey : public InvertibleRSAFunction {
public:
  Integer CalculateInverse(RandomNumberGenerator &rng, const Integer &x) const override {
    return ... // do smart card magic here
  }
};

struct SmartCardRSA : public RSA {
  typedef SmartCardPrivateKey PrivateKey;
};

template <class STANDARD, class H>
struct SmartCardRSASS : public TF_SS<SmartCardRSA, STANDARD, H> {
};
```

Then custom signer object can be constructed

```
SmartCardRSASS<PSS, SHA1>::Signer signer
```

Comment: @roadmap - Yeah, Crypto++ does not always lend itself to subclassing. Its often easier/most efficient to create a new object like you did. I had nearly the exact issue when adding German's digital signature scheme (ECGDSA). There's a reason for it, and its rooted in (1) early C++ dispatch problems; and (2) speed and efficiency. Another thing to watch out for when attempting to subclass... `CRYPTOPP_NO_VTABLE`. It can cause problems on WIndows as objects are flattened. Its defined to nothing on Linux and Unix, so its probably not a problem for you.

Comment: What kind of test rig are you using? We should probably put together a wiki page on the subject. I'm happy to buy the equipment for my test lab as long as its not too expensive. (And sorry about calling you by a different handle. I'm not sure what I was thinking...).